# PyCharm can't find the module of an installed package

Tags: python, pycharm, package

I've installed the package `python-bitcoinlib` in PyCharm however it does not recognize the module `bitcoin` and gives the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SMA/PycharmProjects/HW2/keygen.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bitcoin.wallet import CBitcoinSecret, P2PKHBitcoinAddress
  File "C:\Users\SMA\PycharmProjects\HW2\venv\lib\site-packages\bitcoin\wallet.py", line 29, in <module>
    import bitcoin.core.key
  File "C:\Users\SMA\PycharmProjects\HW2\venv\lib\site-packages\bitcoin\core\key.py", line 33, in <module>
    _ssl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library('ssl') or 'libeay32')
  File "C:\Users\SMA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\SMA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

But I can see the bitcoin folder in the imported libraries.

[image: PyCarm]

Does anybody has any hints?

Comment: Hi, do you have Visual C++ Redistributable Packages installed? It could be a dependency dll problem

Comment: @NipunSampath Hi. Yes I have several different versions of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Packages installed (2005,2008,2010,2012,2013,2015).

Comment: more specifically see if there is a libeay32.dll

Comment: @NipunSampath Thanks a lot! That was the source of the problem. I've downloaded the DLL from [https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/](https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) and the error has been resolved.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer for the benefit of future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the cause of the problem was the missing **"libeay32.dll"**. Problem was solved by downloading it from https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/